# Probability of grabbing pencils and pens from two bins

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The problem is states that there are two bins, Bin #1 which has 3 pens and 7 pencils; and Bin #2 with 8 pens and 4 pencils.

(a) A bin is chosen at random and an object is drawn. What is the probability
that it is a pencil?

I am thinking that this is just

$P(pencil | bin$ #1) $* P(bin $#$1) + P(pencil | bin $#$2) * P(bin $#$2) \ \text{which is} \ (7/10)(1/2)+(4/12)(1/2) = 0.5166$

(b) A bin is chosen at random and an object is drawn. If the object drawn is a
pencil, what is the probability that it came from bin #1?

This question I am not really sure how to approach and I need a bit of help to get started on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it as the ratio of "cases of pencil from bin#1" over "all cases that pencils are drawn".

$${{7\over10}\cdot{1\over2}\over {7\over10}\cdot{1\over2}+{4\over12}\cdot{1\over2}}$$

In general, the probability of E given F $$p(E|F) = \frac{p(E\cap F)}{p(F)}$$

Comment: +1 for a commonsense approach, and  not unnecessarily using the full form of Bayes' Theorem !